# C# and WebClient.UploadFileAsync: howto retain modified date?

Tags: c#, copy, webclient

I use WebClient.UploadFileAsync in order to copy files from one folder to another. It works, but the resulting file in the target directory gets a modified date that corresponds to the time when the file was copied.

When I copy files in Windows explorer, the modified date is untouched.

I'd like to have the same behaviour, how can I achieve that with UploadFileAsync?